# Formula resource in flow to populate a pickval field dependent on a number field I keep getting the error message Syntax error. Missing ')'

Tags: visual-workflow, formula

I am creating a formula resource in flow to populate a pickval field dependent on a number field I keep getting the error message The formula expression is invalid: Syntax error. Missing ')'

but i'm not sure where the the ) should go or if I have just messed up the formula altogether?

```
IF( 
    {!$Record.NumberOfEmployees} >= 1 && 49 <= ISPICKVAL( {!$Record.Tier_Rating__c} "Tier 4"), 
    IF( 
        {!$Record.NumberOfEmployees} >= 50 && 99 <= ISPICKVAL( {!$Record.Tier_Rating__c} "Tier 3" ), 
        IF( 
            {!$Record.NumberOfEmployees} >= 100 && 249 <= ISPICKVAL( {!$Record.Tier_Rating__c} "Tier 2"), 
            IF( 
                {!$Record.NumberOfEmployees} >= 250, ISPICKVAL( {!$Record.Tier_Rating__c} "Tier 1", 
                null
            ) 
        ) 
    ) 
) 
)
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: When facing issues with formulas, your first step should _always_ be to apply proper formatting. Use a new line for each sub-expression, and indent like it were code. This is usually enough to reveal simple issues like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comments, properly formatting your formula makes it easy to see issues.

### The issue

Here, you have 4 main syntax issues:

- You aren't using commas to separate arguments to the `ISPICKVAL()` function
- You don't use a close parenthesis for the final `ISPICKVAL()` function
- You do not provide the third argument to the final `IF()` (and all 3 arguments are *always required*)
- You are improperly trying to compare multiple values to a single input (this is what I assume you are trying to do with `{!$Record.NumberOfEmployees} >= 1 && 49 <=` and the like)

As another note, `ISPICKVAL()` is used to do comparisons against picklists. It *does not set the value* of a picklist. This counts as a *semantic* error (an error in the *meaning* of your formula rather than the *form* of the formula).

### How to fix it

To compare a single field against multiple values, you need to use the field once per comparison

So instead of `{!$Record.NumberOfEmployees} >= 1 && 49 <=`
you would need `{!$Record.NumberOfEmployees} >= 1 && {!$Record.NumberOfEmployees} <= 49`

When you're doing a simple range comparison like this, you can safely assume that subsequent comparisons have already tested the prior comparisons.

So instead of

```java
IF(
    {!$Record.NumberOfEmployees} >= 1 && {!$Record.NumberOfEmployees} <= 49,
    IF(
        {!$Record.NumberOfEmployees} >= 50 && {!$Record.NumberOfEmployees} <= 99,
        ...
```

You can assume that the number is greater or equal to 50 in the second `IF()`. Doing an explicit check for that is just more typing (and thus more chance to make a mistake)

```java
IF(
    {!$Record.NumberOfEmployees} >= 1 && {!$Record.NumberOfEmployees} <= 49,
    'tier 4'
    IF(
        /* 
           To get to this point, the number of employees cannot possibly be
             <= 49, meaning it is at least (or equal to) 50.
           So there is absolutely no need to check for that condition.
        */
        {!$Record.NumberOfEmployees} <= 99,
        'tier 3',
        IF(
            /* 
               Likewise, you don't need to check if the value is >= 100.
               This is logically and mathematically guaranteed, so no check is required.
            */
            {!$Record.NumberOfEmployees} <= 249,
            /* 
               This was the last level of nested IF()
               if you get to the "else" part, then the number of employees
                 is >= 250 (no need to check that).
               Just specify tier 2 for the "then" part, and tier 1 for
                 the "else" part, and your formula should be complete.
            */
        )
    )
)
```

### This is untested

I'm reasonably certain that you can use a formula to assign a value to a flow variable.

What I'm not so sure about is your ability to assign a picklist value using a flow variable.

It's not entirely clear to me why you need to use a picklist ***or a flow*** here in the first place. Simply making this a formula field on your target object should achieve what I assume you're trying to do.

Comment: thank so much for this it has really helped and I will go with your suggestion and use a formula field

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any commas in your `ISPICKVAL` expressions.

e.g.

`ISPICKVAL( {!$Record.Tier_Rating__c} "Tier 4")` should be `ISPICKVAL( {!$Record.Tier_Rating__c}, "Tier 4")`

Also, you can't compare a number with a boolean.

How are you expecting this statement to work?

`49 <= ISPICKVAL( {!$Record.Tier_Rating__c} "Tier 4")`

This will result in either `49 <= true` or `49 <= false`